# How to ensure each worker use exactly one CPU?

Tags: python, numpy, ray

I'm implementing [SEED](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.06591) using ray, and therefore, I define a `Worker` class as follows

```py
import numpy as np
import gym

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, worker_id, env_name, n):
        import os
        os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
        self._id = worker_id
        self._n_envs = n
        self._envs = [gym.make(env_name) 
            for _ in range(self._n_envs)]

    def reset_env(self, env_id):
        return self._envs[env_id].reset()

    def env_step(self, env_id, action):
        return self._envs[env_id].step(action)
```

Besides that, there is a loop in the `Leaner` that invoke methods of `Worker` when necessary to interact with the environment.

As [this document](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html#no-speedup) suggests, I want to make sure each worker use exactly one CPU resource. Here's some of my attempts:

1. When creating a `worker`, I set `num_cpus=1`: `worker=ray.remote(num_cpus=1)(Worker).remote(...)`
2. I checked my numpy configuration using `np.__config__.show()` which gave me the following information

> blas_mkl_info:
>     NOT AVAILABLE
>
> blis_info:
>     NOT AVAILABLE
>
> openblas_info:
>       libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
>       library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
>       language = c
>       define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
>
> blas_opt_info:
>       libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
>       library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
>       language = c
>       define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
>
> lapack_mkl_info:
>     NOT AVAILABLE
>
> openblas_lapack_info:
>       libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
>       library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
>       language = c
>       define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
>
> lapack_opt_info:
>       libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
>       library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
>       language = c
>       define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]

I noticed that numpy is using OpenBLAS, so I set `os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'` in the `Worker` class as the above code does following [this instruction](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_pong_example.html#parallelizing-gradients).

After both are done, I opened top but still noticed that each Worker use `130%-180%` CPUs, exactly the same as before. I've also tried to set `os.environ['OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'` at the beginning of main python script or using `export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=1`, but nothing helps. What can I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pin your core at each worker. For example, you can use something like psutil.Process().cpu_affinity([i]) to pin an index i core at each worker.

Also, before you pin your cpu, make sure to know what cpu has been assigned to the worker by this api. https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/203c077895ac422b80e31f062d33eadb89e66768/python/ray/worker.py#L457

Example:

```py
ray.init(num_cpus=4)
@ray.remote(num_cpus=1) 
def f(): 
   import numpy 
   resources = ray.ray.get_resource_ids() 
   cpus = [v[0] for v in resources['CPU']]
   psutil.Process().cpu_affinity(cpus)
```