# How to run ray correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, ray

Trying to understand how to correctly program with `ray`.

The results below do not seem to agree with the performance improvement of `ray` as explained [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/10x-faster-parallel-python-without-python-multiprocessing-e5017c93cce1).

Environment:

- Python version: 3.6.10
- ray version: 0.7.4

Here are the machine specs:

```
>>> import psutil
>>> psutil.cpu_count(logical=False)
4
>>> psutil.cpu_count(logical=True)
8
>>> mem = psutil.virtual_memory()
>>> mem.total
33707012096 # 32 GB
```

First, the traditional python multiprocessing with `Queue` (multiproc_function.py):

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

N_PARALLEL = 8
N_LIST_ITEMS = int(1e8)

def loop(n, nums, q):
    print(f"n = {n}")
    s = 0
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for e in nums:
        s += e
    t_taken = round(time.perf_counter() - start, 2)
    q.put((n, s, t_taken))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    results = []

    nums = list(range(N_LIST_ITEMS))

    q = Queue()

    procs = []
    for i in range(N_PARALLEL):
        procs.append(Process(target=loop, args=(i, nums, q)))

    for proc in procs:
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        n, s, t_taken = q.get()
        results.append((n, s, t_taken))

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()

    for r in results:
        print(r)
```

The results are:

```
$ time python multiproc_function.py
n = 0
n = 1
n = 2
n = 3
n = 4
n = 5
n = 6
n = 7
(0, 4999999950000000, 11.12)
(1, 4999999950000000, 11.14)
(2, 4999999950000000, 11.1)
(3, 4999999950000000, 11.23)
(4, 4999999950000000, 11.2)
(6, 4999999950000000, 11.22)
(7, 4999999950000000, 11.24)
(5, 4999999950000000, 11.54)

real    0m19.156s
user    1m13.614s
sys     0m24.496s
```

When inspecting `htop` during the run, the memory went from 2.6 GB base consumption to 8 GB, and had all the 8 processors fully consumed. Also, it is clear from `user+sys` > `real` that parallel processing is happening.

Here is the ray test code (ray_test.py):

```
import time
import psutil
import ray

N_PARALLEL = 8
N_LIST_ITEMS = int(1e8)

use_logical_cores = False
num_cpus = psutil.cpu_count(logical=use_logical_cores)
if use_logical_cores:
    print(f"Setting num_cpus to # logical cores  = {num_cpus}")
else:
    print(f"Setting num_cpus to # physical cores = {num_cpus}")
ray.init(num_cpus=num_cpus)

@ray.remote
def loop(nums, n):
    print(f"n = {n}")
    s = 0
    start = time.perf_counter()
    for e in nums:
        s += e
    t_taken = round(time.perf_counter() - start, 2)
    return (n, s, t_taken)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = list(range(N_LIST_ITEMS))
    list_id = ray.put(nums)
    results = ray.get([loop.remote(list_id, i) for i in range(N_PARALLEL)])
    for r in results:
        print(r)
```

Results are:

```
$ time python ray_test.py
Setting num_cpus to # physical cores = 4
2020-04-28 16:52:51,419 INFO resource_spec.py:205 -- Starting Ray with 18.16 GiB memory available for workers and up to 9.11 GiB for objects. You can adjust these settings with ray.remote(memory=<bytes>, object_store_memory=<bytes>).
(pid=78483) n = 2
(pid=78485) n = 1
(pid=78484) n = 3
(pid=78486) n = 0
(pid=78484) n = 4
(pid=78483) n = 5
(pid=78485) n = 6
(pid=78486) n = 7
(0, 4999999950000000, 5.12)
(1, 4999999950000000, 5.02)
(2, 4999999950000000, 4.8)
(3, 4999999950000000, 4.43)
(4, 4999999950000000, 4.64)
(5, 4999999950000000, 4.61)
(6, 4999999950000000, 4.84)
(7, 4999999950000000, 4.99)

real    0m45.082s
user    0m22.163s
sys     0m10.213s
```

The `real` time is much longer than that of python multiprocessing. Also, `real` is greater than `user+sys`. When inspecting `htop`, the memory went up to 30 GB and the cores were also not fully saturated. All these seem to contradict what `ray` is supposed to do.

Then I set `use_logical_cores` to `True`. The run gets killed due to out of memory:

```
$ time python ray_test.py
Setting num_cpus to # logical cores  = 8
2020-04-28 16:27:43,709 INFO resource_spec.py:205 -- Starting Ray with 17.29 GiB memory available for workers and up to 8.65 GiB for objects. You can adjust these settings with ray.remote(memory=<bytes>, object_store_memory=<bytes>).
Killed

real    0m25.205s
user    0m15.056s
sys     0m4.028s
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you change the list to an array `nums = np.arange(N_LIST_ITEMS)`, then the runtime gets cut in half.

Comment: In this case, each Ray worker deserializes the list of integers, which takes up a lot of memory and time. Numpy arrays avoid this issue because Ray stores them in shared memory.

Comment: I think in your example multiprocessing uses `fork` under the hood to create replicas of the program, so workers automatically have a copy of the list, which avoids the deserialization step. This can work in special cases like this where you have a single large (and relatively simple) object that you want all of the workers to have a copy of.

Comment: @RobertNishihara Thx for your reply. I tried `nums = np.arange(N_LIST_ITEMS)` instead of `nums = list(range(N_LIST_ITEMS))`. It is running even slower and takes `real    0m54.076s        user 0m7.388s        sys 0m2.585s`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Ray doesn't guarantee the CPU affinity or resource isolation. That could be the reason why it have non-saturated CPU usage. (I am not 100% sure though). You can try setting cpu affinity using psutil and see if the cores are still not saturated. (https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.Process.cpu_affinity).

About the result, would you mind trying the newest version of Ray? There was pretty good progress in performance & memory management in Ray from the version 0.7.4.

Comment: Thx. I upgraded to ray v. 0.8.4. It ran about 5% faster. I set cpu affinity to use all cores using `p = psutil.Process(); p.cpu_affinity([])` and the results were the same.

Comment: What about the memory usage? Also, you should do in this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61051911/how-to-ensure-each-worker-use-exactly-one-cpu.